# IDs are incremented by omitting some of them

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework

I have an API in written in `NET 6` and a `MSSQL` database. Because I use Entity Framework as `context`, I have a table with migrations where (i don't know if matter, but just to be said)

All tables (api entities) have the IDs incremented automatically. The problem is in `development` mode only. Sometimes, the IDs are incremented by skipping some values and I can't understand why. This is not happening each time when the API is started.

This is a problem for me, because I import my local database into production (I add data in same time with development) and I don't want to have a lot of skipped ids, which may I use later for queries. I don't want to have an id like `899456` instead of `759`.

Can somebody understand and know a solution for this? Or, at least if later is somehow possible (using a tool, SSMS or anothing else which can `rewrite` the `ids` from the starting, even for `foreign keys`).

[image: SQL table ID column]

migration for a table with presented behaviour

[image: table migration]

and the Context model builder configuration for entity `Competition`

```
 private void ConfigureCompetition(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
   modelBuilder.Entity<Competition>()
      .HasKey(e => e.Id);
 }
```

Comment: Can you show us the SQL code to create this table?

Comment: added a print screen with the migration content. I had this problem in past, but I didn't paid attention because the local database was only for development.